# ASP.NET Button Not Calling Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've created an ASP.NET button like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveCoords" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveCoords_Click" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn btn-warning" />
```

and the event in the `OnClick` is defined as follows:

```
protected void btnSaveCoords_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saving Coordinates...");
}
```

When I click the button, `btnSaveCoords_Click` isn't fired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: btnSaveCoords_Click != btnSaveCrop_Click

Comment: OnClick="btnSaveCoords_Click" should be OnClick="btnSaveCrop_Click"

Comment: Typo in copying code, fixed.

Comment: Do you have any message in browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firs row in the .aspx markup file should be like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SportStore.Views.WebForm1" %>
```

Comment: Yes all of that seems in order.

Comment: And are you using any JS library, Ajax...? Is Page_Load event working?? Here is an article from post back in ASP: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2f73dd/what-is-postback-in-Asp-Net/ read it and try to find out what are in two two hidden fields.